# Maven configuration to share resource between modules

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I'm working on a maven project having 2 modules: "impl" which is generating a jar with resources, and "server" which generates a war of server implementation.

```
implementation
    |
    |-impl
    |  |-src
    |  |  |-main
    |  |     |-resources
    |  |-pom.xml
    |
    |-server
    |  |-src
    |  |  |-main
    |  |     |-java
    |  |  |-test
    |  |     |-java
    |  |-pom.xml
    |
    |-pom.xml
```

Currently when I try to create the build, the impl jar file is included in WEB-INF/lib directory of server's war file, so after server war file was generated, it is being unpacked and based on that, all the tests are running, and everything works fine.

As a requirement, I have to separate jar from war, so that war file will not contain any impl's jar file and war will work only if I put the jar file in tomcat's lib directory.

I tried to do it in server's pom.xml file and I set the impl module to provided scope, so the jar file is not longer contained in war, but now the tests are failing, as after unpacking the war file used for running the tests, does not contain the impl jar file which is required for that.
Can I copy the impl's jar file into WEB-INF/lib directory after unpacking the server war file so that tests will work fine, or maybe to set "impl" jar file to behave like it is in server's WEB-INF/lib directory when running the tests, or is there any other possible solution for my issue?

Comment: What about using `<scope>test</scope>` for this jar file which means it is on the test classpath...not being packaged into the war etc. What I don't understand is why you need to unpack your war file for running tests ? What kind of test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify your jar's scope as `provided`. Just include it as a normal dependency in your war's `pom.xml`.
Instead, you can simply configure the [Maven War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html) to **exclude** any files (including jar file) from your `war` file.
You will have to use the `<packagingIncludes>` configuration parameter of the `maven war plugin`.
See the sample code below.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/your_jar_name.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

For more info, you can check this [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html).